# Producing application/octet-stream and application/json

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I have an endpoint that typically returns a document of type PDF, Word, etc. There is user input that goes along with this endpoint, however so I would like to validate it.

The trouble is, when I validate the input and want to return some sort of error JSON response, I end up getting errors similar to

`Failed executing GET /foo/generateBar: NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure: Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: FooResponse of media type: application/octet-stream`

What I am using on my endpoint is `@Produces({"application/octet-stream", "application/json"})`

Is there a way I can avoid this error by possibly returning both JSON and different file formats? My impression is that what the `@Produces` I was using was doing, however I'm probably thoroughly confused.

Additionally, I must note that I'm using `window.open` on the front-end side to call this endpoint.

Comment: If you want to get JSON response from an endpoint that returns JSON and another type of response, you might want to try adding `accept: application/json` to the header of your request.

Comment: @DanielVerem Programmatically, how would I do that in practice? Additionally, I must note that `window.open()` is being used on the frontend side to call this endpoint.

Answer (score 3):

In `Java` and in `javax.ws.rs.core.Response`, you should try something like this in you headers:

```
               Response.status(response.getStatus())
                       .header("Accept", "application/json")
                       .header("Content-type", "application/json")
                       .entity(entity)
                       .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this issue you have to consider the following aspects:

1. **Exceptions mangement**

   Here you have to consider that each time you will have any exception you will throw custom exceptions and an exceptions handler will be implemented using `@ControllerAdvice`, or any other solution. This exceptions handler will return the response as a JSON.
2. **Handling to return the** `application/octet-stream`

   To the endpoint, you need to mention that it will produce `application/octet-stream`. You can use: `@GetMapping(produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM})`.
3. **Provide to the GET request, the proper headers**

   When you are calling the endpoint that produces the `application/octet-stream` you will add the `Accept` header with the value `application/octet-stream, application/json`. Now, in case of success, you'll receive the octet-stream and in case of any exception you'll receive the JSON response.

I hope this solution will help you!