# Is there better approach to Accept Header based content negotiation in Spring API?

Tags: java, spring, rest, content-negotiation

I am using Content Negotiation to define multiple response for the same REST API  function , by changing the accept header.

1. Accept header : **application/json** ,   should give response as json (used by another service)
2. Accept header : **application/octet-stream** , should download the same json response as a file with custom file extension , to be used by UI

Currently i am getting 406 when i pass application/octet-stream in the Accept header.

Is this the right approach ? or should i split the function in to 2 or is it better to use query parameters

Comment: In general, the `Accept` header is just the way HTTP communicates the representation format of the payload sent to the receiver. However, Spring also offers a way to use [file or resource extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33009918/spring-boot-controller-content-negotiation) to do this, however, I'm not a big fan of this approach as a well-behaved client should support the `Accept` header but might not the extension one

Comment: I think the following [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68641098/4507034) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Currently i am getting 406 when i pass application/octet-stream in the Accept header.

Probably, your are using some kind of annotation on your endpoint ...

Something like: `@RequestMapping` or (@GetMapping or @PostMapping, etc) ... well, that annotation contains a `produces` attribute ... that attribute should have the types that your endpoint is expected to produce, in your case: `[application/json, application/octet-stream]` ...

Note: the client should indicate to your endpoint, what kind of format he wants ... to do this, the client should specify the format using the `Accept` http header ...

> Is this the right approach ? or should i split the function in to 2 or is it better to use query parameters?

For me, it is the right approach because your API is simpler and you're using the mechanisms proposed by the standard ...